# In Pyathena can you insert multiple values(Dates) into a SQL parameter?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker, pyathena

I create a dataframe in a Jupyter Notebook instance (AWS Sagemaker) by connecting to an AWS Athena table using a SQL connection like the example below:

I have made a paramter per the link (https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/#query-with-parameter). The parameter is allowing me to insert a single month into the query but fails if I try multiple months - can someone please assist me with how you can insert multiple months into the dictionary :

```
from pandasql import sqldf
from pyathena import connect
from pyathena.pandas.cursor import PandasCursor

curr_month = 202206
prev_month = 202203

conn = connect(work_group='prod_user',
               region_name= 'eu-west-1')

sql_query = ('''
select 
year_month,
id,
field_1,
field_2,
field_3
from
mart.table_xyz
WHERE
year_month = (%(param)s)
;
''')

cursor = connect(work_group='prod_user',
               region_name= 'eu-west-1',
                 cursor_class=PandasCursor).cursor()
user_df = cursor.execute(sql_query,{"param": curr_month}).as_pandas()
```

I have tried a list like below to return two months but that causes an error. Any help would be appreciated

```
cursor = connect(work_group='prod_user',
               region_name= 'eu-west-1',
                 cursor_class=PandasCursor).cursor()
user_df = cursor.execute(sql_query,{"param": [curr_month,prev_month]}).as_pandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to use the `in` operator (not sure about actual python code, but the sql query should look something like `where year_month in (202206, 202203)`):

```sql
WHERE year_month in (%(param)s)
```

And param can be something like `{"param": ', '.join([curr_month, prev_month])}`

Comment: I will have a look into this. Initially it's not looking as the dates are bigint's for that field. It gives a type error so I guess I just convert it. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: @Patty try `', '.join(map(str, [curr_month, prev_month]))` for param

Comment: Thanks it actually came back to the original error, which is why I originally questioned if you can run multiple dates in the parameter -  OperationalError: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 27:16: IN value and list items must be the same type: bigint. I will find information around this error

Comment: @Patty the thing is that _"the original error"_ is not specified in the question. try changing query a bit - `where cast(year_month as int) in ...`